# Unix `ls` command style in CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a very similar result of unix command `ls` in the browser in terms of the arrangement of the items.

Is there any suggestion based on the image below?

While width of the columns depends on the length of the text in that column, number of columns depends on the width of the window.

[image: ls result]

Comment: Can you post a live demo, explain what didn't work and how you tried to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

CSS3 has a new property: [column-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count) and it does exactly what `ls` does (provided you take care of the line breaks, of course). Just use it on your container element, define the size and you're good to go. You can also use `column-gap` to specify the gap between them.

Read more about it here: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/

Comment: I think what OP is looking for is a variable column-count instead of a fixed number.

Comment: @Joren, you could be right, it's hard to understand the question completely. However, if the OP wants that, it can be easily achieved by combining JS with the column-count, right?

Comment: Props for pointing out column-count; I was not aware of this property.